# Referencing to the previous variable (s) within the same chain in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

In the following example, how do I reference the variable(s) within the same chain but computed just earlier:

```
library(data.table)
mtdt<-as.data.table(mtcars)
mtdt[,.(mpg1=mean(mpg),disp1=mean(disp)),by=cyl][,`:=`(mbyd=mpg1/disp1)] # this works
```

But, I was looking for the solution like this:

```
mtdt[,.(mpg1=mean(mpg),disp1=mean(disp),mbyd=mpg1/disp1),by=cyl] 
Error in `[.data.table`(mtdt, , .(mpg1 = mean(mpg), disp1 = mean(disp),  : 
  object 'mpg1' not found
```

I always thought that it was possible to reference the previous variable(s). May be I am missing something here?

P.S. I am NOT looking solution from other packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we need to create three new variables in the existing dataset,

```
mtdt[, c('mpg1', 'disp1', 'mybd') := {tmp1 <- mean(mpg)
                                      tmp2 <- mean(disp)
                                     list(tmp1, tmp2, tmp1/tmp2)}, by = cyl]
```

Or if we are only interested in the summary of the three variables along with 'cyl'

```
mtdt[, {tmp1 <- mean(mpg)
        tmp2 <- mean(disp)
        list(mpg1 = tmp1, disp1 = tmp2, mybd = tmp1/tmp2)}, by = cyl]
#   cyl     mpg1    disp1       mybd
#1:   6 19.74286 183.3143 0.10769950
#2:   4 26.66364 105.1364 0.25361003
#3:   8 15.10000 353.1000 0.04276409
```

Comment: Thanks. I was actually expecting the second solution of mine to work. But, I guess it is not possible.

Comment: @user227710 You have to put that inside braces, and use `list`.

Comment: @ akrun : I will follow your approach. Thanks.